# Во дворе или на дворе?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

"Он пошел во двор" или "он пошел на двор"? Есть ли разница между этими предложениями и, если да, то в чем она? И как вообще правильно говорить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, здесь есть ещё разграничение: смотря откуда пошёл. Идёшь по улице , повернул и пошёл в чей-то двор, т.е. вошёл в ограниченное пространство, во двор.

Находишься в доме, выходишь на воздух, на улицу - на двор. Однако двор - тоже ограниченное пространство, возможно,представляется именно этот ограниченный участок, возможно сказать и во двор. Так что смотря что имеете в виду: участок с забором или выход на воздух из помещения.

Answer (score 4):

В справочнике Розенталя (XLV. УПРАВЛЕНИЕ, §199. Выбор предлога, п. 3 (смысловые различия)объяснение следующе: "Употребление предлога **в** в пространственном значении связано с представлением об ограниченном пространстве, при отсутствии этого значения употребляется предлог **на**. Ср.: машины стояли *во дворе* (окруженное забором или домами пространство) – дети играли *на дворе* (вне дома; ср.: на дворе сегодня холодно)".

Comment: И, тем не менее, "пошел НА кухню". А кухня, особенно в современных квартирах, пространство весьма ограниченное)))

Comment: В комментариях и обсуждениях с недавних пор я не участвую, но Ваш комментарий заставил меня нарушить данное себе слово. Употребление предлогов НА/В (КУХНЕ) не относится к смысловым различиям (на примере ВО/НА двор/дворе). Вариант НА КУХНЕ утвердился под влиянием народной речи. Сравните в литературе: Я побежал в кухню рассказать бабушке всё, что видел и слышал (М. Горький); Нянька приходила на кухню ужинать (В. Короленко).

Comment: + ночь на дворе